# Вывести char32_t как строку

Tags: c++, char, io, wchar-t

1. Что происходит когда мы выводим тип `char`, почему он выводит не число, а символ.
   `char` прогоняется через какую-то функцию, которая подставляет вместо кода символа символ?
2. Почему `char32_t` выводит код символа, а не символ как `char`?
3. Как сделать, чтобы `char32_t` выводил символ/строку вместо кода символа?

```
    char symbol_ch = 'Q';
    cout << symbol_ch << endl;

    wchar_t symbol_wct = L'Q';
    cout << symbol_wct << endl;

    char32_t symbolc32_t = U'Q';
    cout << symbolc32_t << endl;
```

Comment: я так думаю, это связано с перегрузкой operator<<(char/char32_t)

Comment: Для вывода в `cout` `wchar_t` и `char32_t` необходимо преобразовать в (строку) `char` c кодировкой, которая используется в `cout` (обычно ASCII).

Comment: приведите пожалуйста пример, не понимаю зачем мне char32_t преобразовывать к char, и мне нужен юникод

Comment: Кодировки CP1251 , UTF-8 , UTF-32 - разные. А ваша консоль использует только одну. Сначала вы должны узнать свою кодировку консоли , а потом в программе ковертировать в неё.

Comment: У меня все как положено стоит "Active code page: 65001"

Comment: Попробуйте конвертировать [UTF-32 => UTF-8](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/wstring_convert/) Потом можно выводить как UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кодировки **CP1251** , **UTF-8** , **UTF-32** - разные. А ваша консоль использует только одну. Сначала вы должны узнать свою кодировку консоли , а потом в программе ковертировать в неё.

Попробуйте конвертировать [UTF-32 => UTF-8](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/wstring_convert/) Потом можно выводить как **UTF-8**.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <codecvt>
# include <locale>
using std::cout;
using std :: endl;
int main(){

    char symbol_ch = 'Q';
    cout << symbol_ch << endl;

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>,wchar_t> cw;
    cout << cw.to_bytes(L"Алло") << endl;

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>,char32_t> cv;
    cout << cv.to_bytes(U"zß水") << endl;

}
```

---

```
Q
Алло
zß水
```

Comment: `std::codecvt_utf8` объявлен устаревшим в С++17

Comment: компилятор молчит . Вряд-ли что-то изменилось и всё пока пашет. @user7860670

Answer (score -1):

Для вывода вайдовых строк используйте std::wcout

```
wchar_t text[] = L"Hello";
std::wcout << text << std::endl;
```

В случае использования кирилицы возникнут проблемы с кодировкой консоли, но это уже будет совсем другая история

Comment: спасибо, забыл добавить, но это сути вопроса не меняет